Is there a way to open these crates with skulls on them?
Is there a way to open these crates with skulls on them?

On the top is a sort of atom symbol that's similar to the one on God Key doors (I think), but neither the God Key hand blast nor the Überhammer (which is the closest thing to a nuclear weapon) opens them.
I found these in Lab X.

Is it this crate?

If both of the more powerful things failed to open them, I'd say no, but I don't play this game, so I don't know.

@DaemonsMercy No, that's a crate that can be opened with crush-abilities

@Protectorone Have you tried anything besides the God Key blast/Uberhammer?

@DaemonsMercy Various things… None of which worked, obviously
